# How to use Webflow and Next.js within same domain name?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dns, webflow

I have a landing page built in Webflow that's available at https://example.com. Naturally, the CNAME record for example.com points to Webflow.

I also have a Next.js project which contains the page that I want to display at https://example.com/user_id. I don't wish to use a subdomain like xyz.example.com. Is there a way I can achieve this? So that my landing page remains in Webflow (at the same domain) and the rest of the project is on my Next.js deployment.

Not really sure what the best approach here is. Maybe I can somehow get https://example.com to fetch the Webflow page from a different domain?